# Java Regex - Trying to use regex to get an array of "function" arguments

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of strings representing mathematical functions (which could be nested and have any number of arguments), and I want to be able to use regex to return an array of strings, each string being an argument of the outer-most function. Here's an example:

```
"f1(f2(x),f3(f4(f5(x,y,z))),f(f(1)))"
```

I would want a regex pattern that I could use to somehow get an array of all the arguments of f1, which in this case are the strings "f2(x)", "f3(f4(f5(x,y,z)))", and "f(f(1))". There will be no spaces in the input string.

Thank you very much to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with regexes alone.

This would probably require being able to identify balanced parentheses -- for example, once we've parsed `f1(f2(x)`, the next character could either be a `)` or a `,` -- and that's a canonical example of something that *can't* be done with regexes, but requires a more sophisticated parser.

Comment: Dang, really? This is gonna be rough then. Know of any Java utilities that already do anything close to this?

Comment: The reason this is generally impossible with regexp is that regexp have no memory.  There is no general way to let it match nested items, and that's the case with the f3(...) construct above.

Comment: The most general way to do this sort of thing is with a tool like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  Alternatively, roll your own stack-based solution, or a recursive descent parser...but it's not doable with regexes.

Comment: The bright side is that a recursive descent parser will do this easily and are easy to write.

Comment: Recursive descent parser it is. Thanks guys.

Comment: To elabotate on Louis' comment  - it's not 'doable' with regexes _alone_. You can certainly write a simple RDP that uses regexes. If all your inputs are the same format as your exampe, it'll be rather easy.

Comment: @LukeSchafer: Mind giving a quick example maybe? I'm really bad with regex and I've never done an RDP.

Comment: You could, for example, use a regex to match on just the first and last parentheses in a string, and then recurse on the things between the parentheses.

Comment: hmm. ok. Well a quick way to do it is with a regex like ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\((.*)\)$ - this gives 2 capture groups - one with the function name (limited to a-z A-Z and 0-9 characters). The second is the total string of arguments. The tricky part then is splitting the args at the correct level - you could walk a along with a modified regex like the above and record the current level. Another option is go inside out - replace every simple call (as in f(a,b) instead of f(a,f2(b)) with a placeholder like FCALL1, and continuing until you are at the top level. I'm running out of characters :)

Comment: Louis just said what I was trying to say in a much simpler manner :) Refer to his comment :/